# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13d65ccf0 - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have programmatically created a button in my main class and passing an instance of a game class (gameSCNScene - where most of the game logic lies) to the button. Inside this game class instance is where the action for the button resides however when ever I press the button I get the error - Unrecognized selector.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

var gameSCNScene: GameSCNScene!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.delegate = self

    // Create my game scene instance
    gameSCNScene = GameSCNScene(currentview: scnView)

    // Make button
    makeButtonsUI(gameSCNScene)
    }

func makeButtonsUI(gameSCNScene: GameSCNScene) {

    let image = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/addBtn.png") as UIImage?
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:("gameSCNScene.addCube:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

Button function inside my gameSCNScene instance

```
    func addCube(sender:UIButton) {
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but can you try this `button.addTarget(gameSCNScene, action:("addCube:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)`

Comment: Perfect that works thank you

Answer (score 6):

The line of code where you add the target is incorrect. This:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:("gameSCNScene.addCube:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Should be:

```
button.addTarget(gameSCNScene, action:("addCube:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```